# Open a popup when a tree element is selected and tree is opened

Tags: angularjs, treeview

Using `angular.treeview.js`, I would like to simply popup an alert when the parent or child is clicked, at the same time as opening the tree structure. When the child is clicked, show the expanded tree, but also show an alert of the node clicked.

http://plnkr.co/edit/RuUFemqpouPEFIcBBIXh?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-treeview.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller='AngularTree'>
    <div
      data-angular-treeview="true"
      data-tree-id="mytree"
        data-tree-model="roleList1"
        data-node-id="roleId"
      data-node-label="roleName"
            data-ng-click="selectNode(mytree.currentNode.roleName)"
      data-node-children="children">
    </div>
  </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution...

```js
var app = angular.module('demo', ['angularTreeview']);
app.controller("AngularTree", function($scope) {

  $scope.roleList1 = [{
      "roleName": "User",
      "roleId": "role1",
      "children": [{
        "roleName": "subUser1",
        "roleId": "role11",
        "children": []
      }, {
        "roleName": "subUser2",
        "roleId": "role12",
        "children": [{
          "roleName": "subUser2-1",
          "roleId": "role121",
          "children": [{
            "roleName": "subUser2-1-1",
            "roleId": "role1211",
            "children": []
          }, {
            "roleName": "subUser2-1-2",
            "roleId": "role1212",
            "children": []
          }]
        }]
      }]
    },

    {
      "roleName": "Admin",
      "roleId": "role2",
      "children": []
    },

    {
      "roleName": "Guest",
      "roleId": "role3",
      "children": []
    }

  ];

  $scope.selectNode = function(currentNode) {
    $scope.trace = "clicked " + currentNode.roleName;
    $scope.trace += "\nchildren: " + currentNode.children.length;
    // here trying to expand tree on click
    if (currentNode.collapsed) 
     currentNode.collapsed = false;
    else
      currentNode.collapsed = true;
    alert($scope.trace);
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/eu81273/angular.treeview/master/angular.treeview.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/eu81273/angular.treeview/master/css/angular.treeview.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller='AngularTree'>
    <div
      data-angular-treeview="true"
      data-tree-id="mytree"
      data-tree-model="roleList1"
      data-node-id="roleId"
      data-node-label="roleName"
   data-ng-click="selectNode(mytree.currentNode)"
      data-node-children="children">
    </div>
    <pre>trace: {{trace}}</pre>
  </div>
    
  </body>

</html>
```